Tailwind utility classes not detected in source files
I am using Tailwind in a react with vite project and have issues getting tailwind classes to work.
I have tried restarting the project as well as updating npm and node. Similar questions relate specifically to the linting errors in the problem tab but not to the utility classes. Most of the utility classes problems revolved around formatting errors in the tailwind.config.js file. As far as I can tell I do not have that issue here.
This is the warning I get when I start up the dev server.
terminal warning
problems from index.css file.
3 problems from index.css file
tailwind.config.js.
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}

vite.config.js.
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})


postcss.config.js.
export default {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}

package.json.
{
  "name": "comparable-lists",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.66",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.6",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
    "vite": "^5.2.0"
  }
}

index.css.
index.css
main.jsx.
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)


index.html.
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>


app.jsx.
import './App.css'

function App() {

  return (
    <main>
      <h1 className='text-red'>Tailwind with react with vite.</h1>
    </main>
  )
}

export default App


project file structure.
project file structure

With your Tailwind configuration, text-red would not be a valid Tailwind class. I also cannot see any other strings that could be Tailwind classes, hence the error message. The warning should go away once you use a valid Tailwind class in a file covered by the content file globs.
For example, you could use text-red-500 instead of text-red. Also, see the documentation for all the possible text colors you can use.

That is brutal... This fixed the issue. Thank you!
